# How to inspect delayed messages

Tags: c#, servicebus

there is a way to enumerate and inspect delayed messages for Microsoft Windows Service Bus ( not Azure ) ?

I want to do a sort of Peek for only delayed messages, and eventually filter messages to see only specific messages.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 1):

There's a enum `MessageState` that tells you the state of message (Active, Scheduled or Deferred) that is being peeked. Here's how you can do it with the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` package.

```cs
MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("<connection-string>");
QueueClient queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("<queue>");
var scheduledMessages = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
var message = queueClient.Peek();
while (message != null)
{
    // With this condition, you get to filter Scheduled messages
    if (message.State == MessageState.Scheduled)
    {
        scheduledMessages.Add(message);
    }
    message = queueClient.Peek();
}
```

For someone looking for the same with the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package, it can be done like below:

```cs
ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient("<connection-string>");
ServiceBusReceiver serviceBusReceiver = client.CreateReceiver("<queue-name>");
var scheduledMessages = new List<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>();
var message = await serviceBusReceiver.PeekMessageAsync();
while (message != null)
{
    // With this condition, you get to filter Scheduled messages
    if (message.State == ServiceBusMessageState.Scheduled)
    {
        scheduledMessages.Add(message);
    }
    message = await serviceBusReceiver.PeekMessageAsync();
}
```